# Write $f(x) = x \cdot |x|$ as a piecewise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> $$f(x) = x\cdot|x|$$

I was wondering how this function should look if I expanded it to have the format of a piecewise defined function?

I know how to write a piecewise defined function, but the $x$ before the absolute value of $x$ makes it a bit tricky for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Split the domain into $x <0$ and $x \ge 0$. What is $|x|$ on each of these domains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only cases to consider for $f(x)=x|x|$ are $x>0$ and $x \le 0$, since the factor of $x$ is unaffected (i.e. only the factor of $|x|$ is affected).

$$f(x)= x|x| = \begin{cases} -x^2 &=&(x)(-x) & \text{for }x\le0, \\ \ \ \ x^2&=&(x)(x) & \text{for } x>0 \end{cases}$$

For $g(x)=-x|x|$ the definition is completely analogous:

$$g(x) = -x|x|= \begin{cases} x^2 & = & (-x)(-x) & \text{for } x\le 0 \\ -x^2 & = & (-x)(x) & \text{for } x >0 \end{cases}$$

You are right that the definition of $|x|$ is a matter of convention, since for $x=0$ we have $(-1)(0)=0$.

It's better to think of it factor by factor; in some sense it is just an "coincidence" that $x|x|=|x^2|$. The definition of $h(x)=|x|$ is $$h(x)=|x|=\begin{cases} -x & \text{for } x \le 0 \\ x & \text{for } x>0 \end{cases}= \begin{cases} -x & \text{for } x < 0 \\ x & \text{for }x\ge 0 \end{cases}=\begin{cases} -x & \text{for }x <0 \\ 0 & \text{for } x=0 \\ x & \text{for } x>0 \end{cases},$$ so we have for $f(x)=x^2$ that $$|x^2|=h\circ f(x) = \begin{cases}  x^2 & \text{for } x^2 \ge 0 \end{cases}$$ since $x^2\ge0$ always.

Alternatively we could write this as:

$$|x^2|=h\circ f(x) = \begin{cases} -x^2 & \text{for } x^2<0 \\ x^2 & \text{for } x^2 \ge 0 \end{cases}$$

and just note that

$$\{ x: x^2 < 0 \}=\emptyset$$

and

$$\{ x: x^2 \ge 0 \}=\mathbb{R}$$

which implies $|x^2|=x^2$.

Analogously we have:

$$-|x^2|=(-1)(h\circ f(x)) = \begin{cases} (-1)(-x^2) & = x^2  & \text{for } x^2<0 \\ (-1)x^2 & =  -x^2 & \text{for } x^2 \ge 0 \end{cases}$$

and by the same reasoning above it follows that $-|x^2|=-x^2$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: what happens when it is f(x) = -x|x|? Just curious.

Comment: Completely analogous: $$g(x)=-x|x|=\begin{cases} x^2 & = & (-x)(-x) & \text{for }x \le 0 \\ -x^2 & = & (-x)(x) & \text{for } x>0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: I understand that x|x|  = |x^2| but -x|x| = -|x^2|. Can you explain in terms of this, if it is not too much trouble?

Comment: Hi. I am accepting your answer but shouldn't it be for x >= 0 and x <0 in your answer, the equal to should be with > sign. I guess it is just a matter of convention.

Comment: coincidence not accident. :)

Comment: sorry let me write this up in the answer

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
By definition, if $g$ is the piecewise function
$$
g(x) :=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
h_1(x), & x    < a \\
h_2(x), & x \geq a
\end{array}
\right. ,
$$
then the product $(fg)(x)$ is
$$
(fg)(x) = f(x) g(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
f(x) h_1(x), & x    < a \\
f(x) h_2(x), & x \geq a
\end{array}
\right. .
$$

Answer (score 2):

$ f (x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
x (x), & x    \geq 0 \\
x (-x), & x < 0
\end{array}
\right.$